# Knockout.js bind array of objects to repeated <select>'s

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got this Knockout.js view model:

```
{
    "LanguageFromTos":
    [{
        "LanguageFromToId":0,
        "LanguageFromId":2,
        "LanguageFrom":null,
        "AllLanguagesFrom":[
            {"Selected":false,"Text":"English","Value":"1"},
            {"Selected":false,"Text":"French","Value":"2"},
            {"Selected":false,"Text":"Spanish","Value":"3"}
        ],

        "LanguageToId":1,
        "LanguageTo":null,
        "AllLanguagesTo":[
            {"Selected":false,"Text":"English","Value":"1"},
            {"Selected":false,"Text":"French","Value":"2"},
            {"Selected":false,"Text":"Spanish","Value":"3"}
        ],
        "Users":null
    }]
}
```

And these html `<select>`s:

```
<div class="LanguageFromToRow">
    <input type="hidden" name="languageFromTos.index" autocomplete="off" value="c50532b0-65d2-4a81-baeb-59b768fd120f" />

    <label for="languageFromTos_c50532b0-65d2-4a81-baeb-59b768fd120f__LanguageFromId">From</label>:
    <select data-bind="???" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field From must be a number." data-val-required="The From field is required." id="languageFromTos_c50532b0-65d2-4a81-baeb-59b768fd120f__LanguageFromId" name="languageFromTos[c50532b0-65d2-4a81-baeb-59b768fd120f].LanguageFromId">
        <option value="1">English</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2">French</option>
        <option value="3">Spanish</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="languageFromTos[c50532b0-65d2-4a81-baeb-59b768fd120f].LanguageFromId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

    <label for="languageFromTos_c50532b0-65d2-4a81-baeb-59b768fd120f__LanguageToId">To</label>:
    <select data-bind="???" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field To must be a number." data-val-required="The To field is required." id="languageFromTos_c50532b0-65d2-4a81-baeb-59b768fd120f__LanguageToId" name="languageFromTos[c50532b0-65d2-4a81-baeb-59b768fd120f].LanguageToId">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">English</option>
        <option value="2">French</option>
        <option value="3">Spanish</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="languageFromTos[c50532b0-65d2-4a81-baeb-59b768fd120f].LanguageToId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

    <a href="#" class="deleteLanguageFromTo">delete</a>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to add to the `data-bind` attributes of each `select` to tie them up to the Knockout.js view model? The `value` of the first `select` should be bound to `LanguageFromId` in the view model and the `value` of the second `select` should be bound to `LanguageToId` in the view model.

`LanguageFromTos` in the view model is an array, so all of what you see inside may be repeated (2 `LanguageFromTos` would result in the `LanguageFromToRow` div being repeated twice, for example). The number of repeats is set both server-side (data posted by the controller may have multiple `LanguageFromTos`) and client-side (an 'add' button that allows the user to add another div with its contained `select`s) in different cases, so I presume Knockout's templating is a no-go as MVC needs to loop through and render each row so that it can catch them all on a 'normal' post back.

Any help much appreciated!

### Edit

Here's the MVC model for the page:

```
public class DirectorySearchModel
{
    [Display(Name = "User name contains")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First name contains")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last name contains")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Languages translated")]
    public IEnumerable<LanguageFromTo> LanguageFromTos { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the `LanguageFromTo` object:

```
public class LanguageFromTo
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int LanguageFromToId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "From")]
    public virtual int LanguageFromId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LanguageFromId")]
    public virtual Language LanguageFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllLanguagesFrom { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "To")]
    public virtual int LanguageToId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LanguageToId")]
    public virtual Language LanguageTo { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllLanguagesTo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the cshtml code for the MVC view. This code sits in a partial that's repeated depending on how many `LanguageFromTo`s there are in `DirectorySearchModel` that's passed to the MVC view:

```
<div class="LanguageFromToRow">
    @using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("languageFromTos")) {
        @: @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LanguageFromId): @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LanguageFromId, Model.AllLanguagesFrom, new { data_bind = "value: getLanguageFromToById(0).LanguageFromId" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LanguageFromId)
        @: @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LanguageToId): @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LanguageToId, Model.AllLanguagesTo, new { data_bind = "value: getLanguageFromToById(0).LanguageToId" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LanguageToId)
        <a href="#" class="deleteLanguageFromTo">delete</a>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you could slim down that HTML a bit. What's with all the huge long identifiers?

Comment: @SystemParadox thanks for the reply - I've added the mvc model that's passed to the page (and that I want to send back with Knockout.js) and the code for the partial that spits out the horrible identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design here has some poor choices. Knockout's Templating **is** the right choice for this, but it is going to require you to start thinking in a different sort of pattern. You do not need to use partials to accomplish the repetition you are after.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating a templating solution. http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/XgwLD/3/

Some notes: to populate `incomingData`, an easy method will be to use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DirectorySearchModel ));`. This will turn your model into a JSON object, which the viewModel's constructor can easily use.

Now, I didn't use any MVC code in the fiddle because I can't, but you've obviously already found how you can put data-bind in the MVC helpers. This isn't always a bad idea, but for things like selects and DIVs that you want to use as templates, it will probably just makes things harder to read.

Comment: Thanks @Tyrsius! I was a bit concerned that this would mean I couldn't post back to MVC via the more usual submit button, but it works a treat, thanks again!